# Upgrade hard drives to larger size in a RAID 1 Setup on Dell T7500

Tags: raid, dell, hardware-raid

I have a dell T7500 computer.  I currently have 2 300GB drives in RAID1.  I would like to replace these drives with 2 2TB drives that I have and keep the data that is currently installed on the drives.

My thought is the following

1. Turn off system
2. Remove 1 of the 2 drives.
3. Turn on system.  A RAID alert should happen on boot
4. Turn off system.
5. Install 2TB drive.
6. Turn on system, run a RAID rebuild which will populate data on 2TB drive.
7. Turn off system
8. Remove other 300GB drive
9. Turn on system.  A RAID alert should happen on boot
10. Turn off system.
11. Install other 2TB drive.
12. Turn on system and run a 2nd RAID rebuild.

After these steps, should I have a 2TB disk visible in (for example) windows disk management?

Is there a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately not since I consider that you're already a bit oversimplifying it.  You will not be able to increase the size of your raid setup that way.  You should probably do 2 partitions on the new drives so that the first partition matches the current setup.

Comment: I've done this with zero downtime on a Dell with a RAID 5 array. What model PERC do you have? You will have to install the dell openmanage software.

Comment: I just have the Integrated LSI 1068e SAS/SATA raid controller.